# How to group and count events by week?

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary represents an event and has the following form:

```
event1 = {'name': 'event1', 'date':'2015-03-25', 'location':'stackexchange'}
```

How can I group the events into each calendar week (starting from either Monday or Sunday), and count the number of events in each calendar week? E.g. the output can be a list of sublists, each sublist represents the list of events in a corresponding week.

In my code, each 'date' value can be represented either as a string or a `datetime.date` object. I have searched in the `datetime` module and `calendar` module the standard library, but didn't find functions to do the grouping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to do the grouping, based on information you can get from the date. If you store `datetime.date()` objects, you can use the [`datetime.date.isocalendar()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar) to group your dictionaries by year + week number:

```
grouped = {}
for event in list_of_events:
    key = tuple(event['date'].isocalendar()[:1])
    grouped.setdefault(key, []).append(event)
```

You then end up with a dictionary with events grouped per `(year, week)` tuple.

Comment: Thanks. One thing I notice is that only considering weeknumber, will group events in the same week but different years together.  Also can we make the week id starts from 1 which happens for the earliest event, and the id increases by 1 after a calendar week passes even if there is no event?

Comment: @Tim: you can pick any grouping key here; the week number may indeed not be enough so you'd use the year in the key too.

Comment: @Tim: you can renumber those weeks by using the earliest date, take the year and weeknumber, produce an ordinal with `year * 53 + weeknumber` and subtract that base number from there on out. That *may* give you a gap of 1 even if you have dates in every week because a specific year only has 52 weeks rather than 53.

Comment: @Tim: the alternative is to not renumber, but to take the minimum key afterwards, create a date for that week, then keep incrementing that date by 7 days and so produce an incrementing `(year, weeknumber)` key series.